Rounded Bar Chart in Power BI
I wonder if it is possible to create rounded bars in the visualization. I know it is possible in Tableau but is it possible to achieve this effect in Power BI? smth like that:enter image description here
I was looking for something similar in AppSource but I couldn't find it.

Deneb lets you create customize visuals. It uses Vega or Vega-Lite to build these visuals. Below is example Vega-Lite code I used to create a rounded bar chart from my data. cornerRadius can be changed to increase or decrease the bar radius.
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "mark": {
    "type": "bar",
    "cornerRadius": 5
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Month Name",
      "type": "nominal",
      "axis": {"labelAngle": 90}
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "Sum of  Sales",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "title": "Sales"
    }
  }
}

Output:

